# Trouble using NSUserDefaults with suiteName in Xcode 6.1 (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm having trouble using `NSUserDefaults` with `suiteName` in Xcode 6.1. This code worked previously, but now there is a Swift Compiler Error.

```
var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.example.myAppGroup")
userDefaults.setObject("test", forKey: "test")
```

Swift Compiler Error: `NSUserDefaults? does not have a member named 'setObject'`

When using `standardUserDefaults()`, it works as expected:

```
var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.setObject("test", forKey: "test")
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong when using `suiteName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `NSUserDefaults(suiteName:)` returns an optional, as it says in the error message.
So to fix, either you set your object this way:

```
userDefaults?.setObject("test", forKey: "test") // note the ? mark
```

or extract the value immediately from the initializer:

```
var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.example.myAppGroup")! // note the ! mark
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSUserDefaults(suiteName:)` returns an optional `NSUserDefaults`. You should use optional binding to make sure it's valid and unwrap it before using it:

```
if let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.example.myAppGroup") {
    userDefaults.setObject("test", forKey: "test")
}
```